# Rspec testing associations with expect change syntax

Tags: rspec, associations

I'm trying to test some associations with rspec.
Here is my test:

1)

```
it 'creates an incubation with proper associations' do
  expect{post :apply_startup, id: incubator.id, startup: {id: startup.id}}
    .to change{incubator.pending_startups.count}.from(0).to(1)
end
```

2)

```
it 'creates an incubation with proper associations' do
  expect{post :apply_startup, id: incubator.id, startup: {id: startup.id}}
    .to change{incubator.pending_startups}.from([]).to([startup])
end
```

This is the definition of `apply_startup` method:

```
def apply_startup
  startup = Startup.find_by_id params[:startup][:id]
  @incubator.pending_startups << startup if startup
  redirect_to incubator_path(@incubator)
end
```

First test passes, but the second failed.

Edit#1 (output of failed spec)

```
2) IncubatorsController#apply creates an incubation with proper associations
 Failure/Error: expect{post :apply, id: incubator.id, startup: {id: startup.id}}
   result should have initially been [], but was [#<Startup id: 665, ********]
```

Could somebody explain, why?
Thanx

Comment: What is the full output from RSpec about the failure of the second test?

Comment: sorry, just updated a question.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your database isn't being reset between each spec. Are you using `database_cleaner`?